# Prevent New Line Using Razor Conditional Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to display some `html` content using the `razor` syntax, based on some variable contained in the `ViewBag` object. Current the content breaks to newline after the conditional statement. This is what I have:

```
<h5>Apply salary @ViewBag.salaryStatus to associated objects?</h5>
    @if (ViewBag.salaryStatus == "Executed")
    {
        <h5>(This will overwrite old values of the selected objects).</h5>
    }
```

Actual result is:

```
Apply salary reviewed to associated objects?
(This will overwrite old values of the selected objects).
```

Expected result is:

```
Apply salary reviewed to associated objects? (This will overwrite old values of the selected objects).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding multiple H5 elements. These are block HTML elements and will by default be put on a new line. You should only create a single H5 element like so:

```
<h5>Apply salary @ViewBag.salaryStatus to associated objects?
@if (ViewBag.salaryStatus == "Executed")
{
    <text>(This will overwrite old values of the selected objects).</text>
}
</h5>
```

Comment: I think the code block in the `if` statement needs to be enclosed, or else it is giving a compilation error.

Comment: You could also use the `@:` sequence if you don't like the `<text>` pseudo-tag - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax

Answer (score 0):

you can also use below logic;

```
@{
   var message = "";
   if () {
      message = "your message";
   }
}
<h5>Apply salary @ViewBag.salaryStatus to associated objects? @message</h5>
```